# ng-model not working in select tag under ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, html-select, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-select

This is html page

```
<form name="createPromoterFormName">
            <div class="col s12" ng-repeat="customer in model.customers" ng-if="model.selectedCustomerSubtab == $index">
            <div class="row inputcontainer">
                <div class="input-field col s4">
                    <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" ng-model="customer.customer_name" class="validate" ng-maxlength="50" ng-required="true" />
                    <label class="active labelName">Customer Name </label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s4">
                    <input type="text" class="validate" ng-maxlength="50" ng-required="true" ng-model="customer.avg_monthly_sales" />
                    <label class="active labelName">Average Monthly Sales </label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s4">
                    <select ng-model="customer.avg_payment_cycle_days" ng-options="i.value as i.value for i in model.avgPaymentCycleDays" ng-change="changeSelectedItem()">
   <option value="">Select Average Payment Cycle Days</option>
</select>
                    <label class="labelName">Avg Payment Cycle Days [[customer.avg_payment_cycle_days]]</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row inputcontainer">
                <div class="input-field col s4">
                    <input type="text" class="validate" ng-maxlength="50" ng-model="customer.avg_paymmonths_in_business_with_customerent_cycle_days" />
                    <label class="active labelName">Months in business with customer</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </form>
```

Controller.js

```
$scope.model = {  
    customers: [{
        customer_name: "",
        avg_monthly_sales: "",
        avg_payment_cycle_days: "",
        months_in_business_with_customer: ""
    }, {
        customer_name: "",
        avg_monthly_sales: "",
        avg_payment_cycle_days: "",
        months_in_business_with_customer: ""
    }, {
        customer_name: "",
        avg_monthly_sales: "",
        avg_payment_cycle_days: "",
        months_in_business_with_customer: ""
    }],
    avgPaymentCycleDays : [{
        value: '15',
        id: '1'
    }, {
        value: '30',
        id: '2'
    }, {
        value: '45',
        id: '3'
    }, {
        value: '60',
        id: '4'
    }, {
        value: '75',
        id: '5'
    }, {
        value: '90',
        id: '6'
    }],
    selectedPromoterSubtab: 0,
    selectedCustomerSubtab: 0,
}


$scope.changeSelectedItem = function() {
    console.log($scope.model.customers);
}
```

[image]
I am using material css. When I am selecting option, ng-change is not getting trigger  and also not binding data to ng-model.

Can anybody help me where am I making mistakes?

[This is plnkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/dXylCeX2KcXT5HVk8WOW?p=preview)

Comment: i created a plunker based on your code and it seems to work fine. https://plnkr.co/edit/Zq8PDunpAh82Sij8WnAO?p=preview . something else must be breaking it.

Comment: @Deep: I agree with you. Working fine in my case too. Check if your javascript is loading or other basic things like file path etc. Or share your complete controller.

Comment: I have kept input boxes as well ...there ng-model data binding is working , but not for select

Comment: what is your exact problem? I can see the ng-change is working fine. are you concerned about that the ng-model in select is not selecting the option properly?

Comment: Avg Payment Cycle Days [[customer.avg_payment_cycle_days]]  This data is not binding ...nothing coming on screen

Comment: check the plunker   https://plnkr.co/edit/Zq8PDunpAh82Sij8WnAO?p=preview . Label is populated correctly.

Comment: @Deep :  I am trying to get this :  https://plnkr.co/edit/dXylCeX2KcXT5HVk8WOW?p=preview

Intiallly select input was not coming so I was initializing it by my own

Comment: This is my problem ....please check this :  https://plnkr.co/edit/dXylCeX2KcXT5HVk8WOW?p=preview

not binding data in select using ng-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the order in which you have included the script file.

Check the plunker.

https://plnkr.co/edit/eFL48s3UyhwdTFzwTR05

the ng-model is binding properly and the ng-change is also getting fired properly.

```
<script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks ....I have wasted half day to fix this issue ....Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

First of all ng-selected is not required. ng-model will automatically detect whatever has to be selected from the dropdown, if dropdown has that value.

So change your select to

```
<select ng-model="customer.avg_payment_cycle_days" ng-options="i.value as i.value for i in model.avgPaymentCycleDays" ng-change="changeSelectedItem()">
   <option value="">Select Average Payment Cycle Days</option>
</select>
```

Also include jquery as per your plnkr, you have not included that

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
```

Here is the working plnkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/p7t7KcNmChZlT5Jg0pr2?p=preview

Comment: changeSelectedItem()  function even not working in my controller ....nothing is printing

Comment: it is working fine in my case. Two things 1) Have you changed your interpolation from {{ }} to [[]]? 2) Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: Yes , I have used interpolation ...no error in console

Comment: I have updated HTML page ....I am getting ng-model data values for other input boxes

Comment: What are you getting in select dropdown?

Comment: Also do not use ng-repeat in dropdown but ng-options will do the trick as per my answer

Comment: Please check my HTML page page

Comment: Is it something happening because of material-css ?

Comment: No it should not be because of that. I hope you have defined your interpolation thing correctly.

Comment: There is no issue with  interpolation........ I am initilizing material select like this :  $('select').material_select(); ..... I think its creating some problem

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/dXylCeX2KcXT5HVk8WOW?p=preview

Please see this ...This is what I am tryinng to doing

Comment: select dropdown is not coming in plunkr...but if you initialize   by this in console    $('select').material_select();  this is will come ...

Comment: Please have a look into plnkr and try to bind element in select ng-model  : https://plnkr.co/edit/dXylCeX2KcXT5HVk8WOW?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, I am little late, but here if the working plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/p7t7KcNmChZlT5Jg0pr2?p=preview